# Putting two of the same words together in a sentence has always bothered me

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

Why is there nothing wrong with this sentence where the preposition *for* is doubled in the sentence?

> Little does she know that this chance meeting with the gentleman with the alluring green eyes sends her life into a whirlwind of events which she had been praying **for for** a long time.

Comment: There's nothing technically wrong with it.  Either accept it or reorder the sentence to avoid it.

Comment: First: *wait for*; second: *for a long time*.  If you don't want the immediate repetition, you could change it, e.g., *Little does she know this chance meeting will send her life into a long prayed for whirlwind of events -- but of course this sentence does have some other problems (as does the original).  One does not pray for a long time for a whirlwind of events.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am always concerned about the "rules" of grammar when that happens.  What are you referring to when you say the original sentence has  problems as well?

Comment: It's not *wrong*, but if you don't like it then say it differently.  English offers many ways to say the similar things, so you don't need to be satisfied with one you don't like.    "...which had been a subject of her prayers for a long time", "... that she had been praying for since she was a little girl", "... that answer prayers she had been making for a long time", etc...

Comment: *Smith and Jones, who both had taken an English exam,  had disgreed on a question about past tenses. Smith, unlike Jones who had had 'had', had had 'had had'. 'Had had' had had the examimers' approval.* (You're welcome. And if that sentence bothers you, maybe don't read [this](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/58832-good-item-seven-the-had-had-and-that-that-problem).)

Comment: @aparente001 - It's true that one doesn't pray for a whirlwind of events, but one may have been praying a long time for several different events only to find that an unexpected meeting with a green-eyed gentlemen results in all of the events occurring at the same time.

Comment: @nnnnnn - Fine.  You can read that book and enjoy the whirlwind.  I'll give it a miss.

Answer (score 1):

While it may seem like 'for' is being doubled on its own, what we actually have is two different semantic units, both of which contain 'for,' but which operate independently:

In the first instance, the [phrasal verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrasal_verb) 'to pray for' is used.

> to wish for fervently, to hope. [OED 1 a](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/149429?rskey=yYi1i7&result=3&isAdvanced=false#eid)

This contains the preposition 'for,' but 'for' is inseperable, since the meaning of the verb 'to pray' [OED 1 b](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/149429?rskey=yYi1i7&result=3&isAdvanced=false#eid) is different from the verb 'to pray for.' Confusingly, in English, they are constructed from and appear under the same lemma.

In the second instance, 'for' is a preposition of duration, 'for a long time' [OED A X 27](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/72761?rskey=16mUBx&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid)

Neither is redundant to the other, and neither can be cut without changing the meaning of the sentence. (That said, the sentence could bear some rewriting for a number of stylistic reasons, not just to avoid doubling 'for.')

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways words get doubled in a sentence, accidentally when two common phrases are strung together, and intentionally for emphasis or for poetic word play. The sentence above is an accidental word doubling.

In the fragment, "praying for for a long time", "praying for" is a common way to indicate the thing for which she was praying, which was just indicated. The "for a long time" is also common phrasing to indicate the passage of time. Combining those two thoughts accidentally doubles up a word. Yes, the sentence can be rewritten to eliminate the word doubling, but why? This is commonly accepted English usage.

Another often read/heard phrasing of accidentally doubled words is, "I told you that that would happen [if you kept running with scissors]." The first 'that' recalls to mind a past event, "I told you ". The second 'that' is for the referenced thing that happened.

Intentionally doubled word usage is very very common in English prose to stress the importance of a word. Poetically, for example, "It's a hard hard world" in the lyrics of *Slip Kid* by The Who, or in the title of the country song *Hard Hard World* by Sawyer Brown.

Word play might give doubles like, "I love love and hate hate."

Comment: Good answer. There is a third way: incorrect doubling. E.g., it's become relatively common for people to double "is" in a way that makes no sense. (Usually only in speech, not in writing.)

Comment: This answer incorrectly identifies what is actually happening in the sentence. 'for' is neither accidentally or poetically doubled: the first instance is part of a phrasal verb, 'to pray for.'